# How to reindex to merge two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two dataframes that both have a 'product_desc' column. I am using Pandas 0.13 and Python 2.7.

```
small_df = pd.merge(small_df, linregress_df, on = 'product_desc', how = 'left')
```

However, I get the following error:

```
pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I exported both dataframes to flat files and there are no duplicate values for the indexes or other columns in either. What do I need to do so these two dataframes will merge?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: could be a bug, could you try upgrading to 0.13.1 or 0.14.0

Comment: You're not calling `get_duplicates`, that line should read `small_df.index.get_duplicates()` (note the parentheses). And you shouldn't be looking for duplicates in the index, look for them in the `product_desc` column (`small_df['product_desc'].duplicated()`).

Comment: @U2EF1 Yes, you are correct on get_duplicates. There were no duplicates when I had the correct function. However, I still get the above error message when I try to merge.

Comment: It might help to have a full stack trace of the error in your question. I have no idea what goes wrong - but for a start you could try to subset your data and see if the merge works.

Answer (score -1):

The merge function takes four arguments: dataframe 1, dataframe 2, left_on = "dataframe 1 column", right_on = "dataframe 2 column which matching values in dataframe 1"

Here's how I would do it if the matching columns in both data frames are named the same:

```
small_df = pd.merge(small_df, linregress_df, left_on = 'product_desc', right_on = 'product_desc')
```